# Posting to Node Endpoint from JavaScript on web page using setInterval loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I want to run a web page that posts data to a web endpoint ~every second.  With the NodeJS and browser JS below it seems to work and synchronize well for the first 6 requests.  After the first 6 requests I can see submissions happening from the browser that aren't logging in Node for quite sometime.  eventually my browser will report some "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" errors.

**NodeJS Endpoint code:**

```js
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express()

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3000')
})

app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

**testPost.JS from the web page:**

```js
var num = 0;
var theDate;
var theTime;

setInterval(function () {
    theDate = new Date();
    theTime = theDate.toLocaleTimeString();
    num++
    send({Time: theTime, Num : num});
}, 10000);

function send(theData) {
    console.log('Send Function Start: ' + JSON.stringify(theData))
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(theData),
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
            console.log('success: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

**The web page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="testPost.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
app.post('/',function(request,response){
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

This creates a pending request that is will not finish, because you do not call `response.send` or `response.end`.

After a certain time the browser will timeout the pending request, and you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I added response.end but it didn't change the responses at all.  app.post('/',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
    response.end;
});

Comment: @Ken you have to **call**  the `end` function, just writing `response.end;` does not do anything. ([express: res.end](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.end))

Comment: Thank you.  Updated as follows and appears to work well.          app.post('/',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
    response.json({'status' : 'ok'});
    response.end();
});